# recaptcha model is blank vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

**Problem**

loginForm.recaptcha is always blank. Am I missing anything?

**Component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-recaptcha  v-model="loginForm.recaptcha"
            sitekey="My key">
        </vue-recaptcha>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return { 
                loginForm: {
                    recaptcha: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.component('vue-recaptcha', VueRecaptcha);
```

I can confirm that the captcha is rendering successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue-recaptcha` as no `value`/`v-model` property. You can use the `verify` event:

See [**demo JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/r3twpt2n/).

Code:

```js
Vue.component('vue-recaptcha', VueRecaptcha);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loginForm: {
      recaptcha: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    recaptchaVerified(response) {
     this.loginForm.recaptcha = response;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer>
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-recaptcha@latest/dist/vue-recaptcha.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div>
        <vue-recaptcha @verify="recaptchaVerified"
            sitekey="your key">
        </vue-recaptcha>
    </div>
   loginForm: {{ loginForm }}
</div>
```

Comment: can u suggest here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364689/captcha-form-validation-required-error-message-in-vue-recaptcha